# Tyres for puncture resistance for mountain biking on rocky dry terrain (folding & lightweight)

Tags: tire

I need a tyre that is really durable, puncture resistance, folding, lightweight and good for rocky (sometimes loose) and dry terrain. I work as a guide in Georgia (Caucasus) and my tyres wear out too quickly.

Comment: Avoiding specific tyres (since [product recs are off-topic on this site](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), a kevlar layer is good for puncture resistance (a belt, not a bead). Durability is more difficult - I know there is something called the Shore Scale which is used to measure the hardness of rubber compounds (presumably you'd want something quite hard) but as far as I know this scale has not caught on with bicycle tyres.

Comment: I tend to think that lightweight on the one side and puncture resistance and durability on the other side don't go along well. I have my puncture resistant tyres for about 40000 km now (mostly on asphalt, little gravel), but they're definitively not lightweight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really like some of the WTB tires.  Specifically the Bronson and the Weirwolf.  It's tough to find a tire that's going to do it all, but I think WTB is a good mix between weight and durability.  I also really like the traction of those two tires in a lot of varying conditions.

When you say "they wear out too quickly" how quickly are we talking?  How many miles/rides/weeks...

Another thing to consider, if you are riding tubeless (or willing to do the conversion) I have had really good luck with Stan's sealant to keep punctures to a minimum.

Also, are the tires wearing out due to treadwear, punctures, sidewall tears?  Those two tires are a really good balance all around but if you have specific concerns/issues, you might get some better recommendations.